# Setting time zone in service fabric cluster

Tags: timezone, azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to set the timezone of a service fabric cluster to something other that UTC (CET for example)?

I know it is not the best approach, but if it would be supported it would save my team a lot of time.

Comment: What are your requirements for having times in none UTC? You can log on to each node and change the timezone yourself, or use a powershell script, etc..

Comment: This is a legacy code that I would like to migrate to service fabric. Unfortunately it relies in DateTime.Now() across the board.

Can I somehow have the "set timezone powershell" every time I add machines to my service fabric cluster?

Comment: You can use a VM provisioning extension to run arbitrary executables or scripts on creation. Forgotten what it's called - but yes it is possible!

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-vmss-custom-script-windows/ may help!

Comment: If you have the code, it would be very recommended to do this in code instead.  Refactor your `DateTime.Now` calls to your own method that uses `DateTime.UtcNow` and `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` to get it into your desired time zone.